# is it specified how idols in temples should be dressed (garments, ornaments etc.)?

Tags: idols, dress

Male idols typically wear dhotis, female idols sarees.  there are also non-human idols like sudarshana chakra.

should they be dressed in specific ways per scripture?

Comment: The garments apparently look very similar in ISKCON temples.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Garments, clothes and Ornaments are part of the idol's paraphernalia.

Quoting from Agni Purāṇa

> [Chapter 44](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083132.html)
>
> 46. **The image should be adorned with ornaments.** This is the exact description of details. The features (of the deities) should be made
>     in this world, as described.
> 47. A disc on the (upper) right hand, and a lotus on the lower (right hand), the conch on the (upper) left hand, the mace on the lower (left
>     hand) **are to be placed according to the characteristic of Vāsudeva**.

So, As per the different vyuhas/sub-vyuha of the deity the weapons, and other accessories are sculpted in the idol.

> [Chapter 58](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083149.html)
>
> 23. The image should be rubbed part by part and perfumes (should be offered) with (the syllable) gandhavat [?note?], garland with (the
>     syllable) unnayāmi and **the sacred thread** with (the syllable) idaṃ
>     viṣṇu.
> 24. **Pair of cloth pieces (should be offered) (with the syllable) bṛhaspate (and) the upper cloth (with the syllable) vedāham.** The herbs
>     and the flower of concluding worship should.. be placed with the
>     mahāvrata.

**edit:**

Another reference I found in the Brahma Purāṇa

> [Chapter 47](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216117.html) - The Origin of Idols
>
> Brahmā said:
>
> (48.) **On hearing his words, Viśvakarmā did all efficiently,
> instantaneously. He made the idols of auspicious traits.**
>
> (49). The ear-rings were of wonderful design and shone in the ears.
> The hands were kept on the discus and ploughshare, Kṛṣṇa holding the
> discus and Balarāma the ploughshare. The idols were approved of by the
> pious people.
>
> (50-51). The first idol had white lustre and colour. It was as
> refulgent as the autumnal moon. The eyes were reddish. The body was
> huge and the head looked savagely fierce due to the hoods. **It was
> the fierce Balarāma who was clad in blue robes,** He was haughty and
> intoxicated due to his inordinate strength. **He wore a single
> ear-ring. He had a divine form. He held the iron club and the
> threshing rod.**
>
> (53). to. 53. **The second idol was Viṣṇu’s.** His eyes resembled the
> lotus; his body the blue cloud. He shone like the Atasi flower. His
> eyes were as large as the petals of the lotus. **He had yellow
> garments.** He was very fierce and auspicious. He was marked by the
> characteristic sign of Śrīvatsa. The discus filled one of his hands.
> He had a divine form that dispelled sins.
>
> (54). to 55. **The third idol made by Viśvakarmā was that of
> Subhadrā.** She had the colour and lustre of gold. Her eyes were large
> like the petals of a lotus. **She was clad in robes of various and
> wonderful colours. She was bedecked in necklaces and shoulderlets. She
> was adorned by wonderful ornaments.** Gem-studded necklaces dangled
> round her neck. Viśvakarmā made her very beautiful with plump and
> elevated breasts.
>
> (56). to 57. **On seeing this wonderful deed of making the idols in a
> trice, on seeing that the beautiful idols richly endowed with all
> characteristic signs, clad in a pair of divine clothes and adorned by
> different jewels were made quickly,** the king was excessively
> surprised and he spoke thus.
>
> English Translation by G.P. Bhatt

So yes, the idol of the deities should be dressed in specific ways per scripture, as depicted and made by the Viśvakarmā himself!

**edit 2**

In the Mānasāra śilpaśastra, we get a good description of the idol of thd Trimurtis and how exactly they maybe sculptured and decorated with clothes & ornaments, etc.

> [Chapter 51](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manasara-english-translation/d/doc421099.html)
>
> - #### Brahma
>
> 26. It (the image of Brahmā) should have four arms, four faces, two legs, and eight eyes.
>
> ....
>
> 34. There should be put on the sacred thread, the upper garment etc., and a belt all round the belly.
> 35. It should be adorned with the chain put over the upper neck, and with garlands round the arms.
> 36. and. It should also be adorned with the armlets, keyūra, and kaṭaka, etc.,
> 37. and the wristlets (maṇibandha); and there should be three
>     armlets (kaṭaka) including the one round the arm (nalaka).
> 38. There should be the chain, etc., and the plates for the hip, and the loin-cloth connected with the thighs (calana, lit., leg).
>
> ---
>
> - #### Vishnu
>
> 45. It (the image of Viṣṇu) should be furnished with four arms, two eyes, and the crowns known as the kirīṭa and the makuṭa[5].
> 46. It should put on yellow clothes, and the whole body should be given the bright blue complexion.
>
> ....
>
> 55. It should put on a chain over the neck, and also the sacred thread and the upper garment.
> 56. There should be a jewel belt round the belly, and the arms should be adorned with garlands.
> 57. It should put on lower armlets, belt round the waist, upper armlets, and the ear-ornaments (pūrita) made of precious stones.
> 58. The fingers should be adorned with rings of precious stones, and the net-ornaments should be put on the feet.
> 59. The suspending yellow clothes should reach the thigh or the knee.
> 60. The nimbus (śiraścakra, lit., head-disc) should be put at the back of the head, and all the limbs should be gracefully ornamented.
> 61. The beautiful wild flower garland should extend down to the two legs.
>
> ---
>
> - #### Shiva
>
> 65. It (the image of Śiva) should be furnished with four arms, three eyes, and be adorned with the matted hair and the makuṭa crown.
> 66. It should be decorated with the tiger’s skin cloth above the knee and thigh.
> 67. It should be decorated with a piece of suspending cloth round the waist, and the body should be beautifully red in complexion.
> 68. It should put on a chain over the neck hanging down to the chest, and there should be a suspending garland round the forehead.
> 69. There should be a jewel belt of the elephant’s cheek pattern
>     (karaṭa), or a very tight (rudra, terrible) belt (? around the waist);
> 70. and a leaf ornament, or plain belt, or jewel belt round the belly.
> 71. It should be decorated with the lower armlet, a hip-chain, the upper armlet (keyūra), and the ear-ornaments (pūrima).
> 72. The root of the arms should be decorated with garlands and with all (other) ornaments.
>
> English Translation by Prasanna Kumar Acharya

**So, yes *it specified how idols in temples should be dressed (garments, ornaments etc.)*!**

Comment: all fine and dandy @vivikta - but I am looking for Agamic rules designed to maintain the power and sanctity of idols.

Comment: Of Which (Agamic rules, powers, and sanctity, etc.) you haven't mentioned in the question at all! @SK

Comment: sorry if I didn't make it clear @vivikta .